# QSystemtrayicon: no image on Mac

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a problem with the `QSystemTrayIcon` class on Mac and Linux.

I made a program creating a System tray icon, and I have no problem on Windows, but under Linux (ubuntu 12) and Mac (OSX 10.8), the tray icon is here, but the image on it doesn't show up.

This is what I'm doing in the `ctor` of my class:

```
icon = new QIcon("trayIcon.png");
m_pTrayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon();
m_pTrayIcon->setIcon(*icon);
m_pTrayContextMenu = new QMenu();
m_pTrayContextMenu->addAction(openSettings);
m_pTrayContextMenu->addAction(switchSyncMode);
m_pTrayContextMenu->addAction(openFolder);
m_pTrayContextMenu->addSeparator();
m_pTrayContextMenu->addAction(quit);
m_pTrayIcon->setContextMenu(m_pTrayContextMenu);
m_pTrayIcon->show();
```

I'm using the Qt 4.8 library.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Have you checked that trayIcon.png is in the program's working directory ?

Comment: Yes, of course. I put it in the same directory than the executable file

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities

1. It cannot find the file. Try what happens if you give the global path.
2. It cannot load the png; see if loading QT module Multimedia helps.